# // @sourceurl on script tag in firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

In firefox 19 and firebug 1.X I encountered a strange bug when trying `//@sourceurl`.

Basically I'm dynamically adding script tag through dom manipulation as you can see in the sample below. This does not work.

Maybe it's a limitation of ff but I find it odd that it works in chrome and not in ff.
Can you **confirm** this and do you have any **bypass** to this bug?

*Ps: I don't want to use global `eval()` as it crash in ie when using `document.write`*

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var count=0;
    function addNewScriptToHead()
    {
            var newScriptElem;
            var newScriptText;

            newScriptElem = document.createElement('script');
            newScriptElem.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            newScriptElem.setAttribute('id', '' + count);
            newScriptElem.text= 'console.log("Yay !");//@ sourceURL=root/test'+count++ +'.js';

            document.body.appendChild(newScriptElem);
    };
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <button onclick="addNewScriptToHead()">add script</button><br><br>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't you have to escape the double slash? How come it's not treated as a comment in your original script?

Comment: because it is in a string of course :)

Answer (score 2):

Experimentation has lead me to believe the following:

1. As of version 20.0, FF still does not support `//@ sourceURL` directly in its inbuilt web console.
2. `//@ sourceURL` does work with the Firebug addon in FF, but not completely as expected/hoped.

   A. It *only* works for `eval`. It doesn't work at all for appended
   script nodes like in the original question.

   B. Errors will have a line number and the URL, and you can click
   the error to see the line of code. However, `console.log` does not
   seem to be affected and shows no line number or URL.
3. Testing this feature from within FF's web console is not advised. I got different results than testing directly in HTML at least some of the time.